# zsh completion for cssh: complete hosts from /etc/hosts as well as ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete, hosts

my zsh completion file `_cssh` has this line, which completes hosts only from /etc/hosts:

```
'*:userhostport: _alternative hosts:host:_hosts usersathosts:userathost:_user_at_host'
```

how do I make it complete hosts defined in my ~/.ssh/config, same as ssh does ?
the full _ssh file is [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABI8qB3EQ)

I don't need to complete usernames. Just hostnames from `/etc/hosts` as well as hosts defined in `~/.ssh/config`. Also, it is important that multiple hosts can be completed (cssh is cluster ssh and takes multiple hosts, unlike ssh)

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try to update the `alternative` from both `/etc/hosts` and `~/.ssh/config.`

`"*:userhostport: _alternative 'hosts from /etc/hosts:hosts:host:_hosts' 'hosts from ~/.ssh/config:hosts:host:_ssh_config_hosts' usersathosts:userathost:_user_at_host"`

And adding the function below to the `_cssh` file, before the `_cssh` function definition.

`_ssh_config_hosts() { local hosts hosts=("${(@f)${(ps:\n:)${(f)"$(<$HOME/.ssh/config)"}:#Host*}") _describe -t hosts 'hosts from ~/.ssh/config' hosts }`

Then you should be Ok with `/etc/hosts` and `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: I have applied your changes, but it does not work and I get: `_cssh:2: unmatched "` error. Here is the complete `_cssh` file: https://ctxt.io/2/AABISTd9Fg

Comment: Can you try this.

```'*:userhostport: _alternative "hosts from /etc/hosts:hosts:host:_hosts" "hosts from ~/.ssh/config:hosts:host:_ssh_config_hosts" "usersathosts:userathost:_user_at_host"'```

Comment: `_cssh:2: unmatched "`